# How to prevent jquery sortable portlets from assigning when not over them

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

When using jqueryui's sortable plugin, there is the problem that once you have moved your mouse over a drop location after you started the drag it will remember that and drop it there even if you are not over anything when releasing the mouse.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, so that the dragged portlet jumps back to it's original position if it is not over a drop location when releasing the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

I have a work around to prevent the inappropriate assignment, my code is more complex so I stripped this down to the bare necessity.

Use the OVER event to add a hover class to the target

```
over: function(event,ui){
  $(this).addClass('hover');
}
```

Use the OUT event to remove the hover class from the target

```
out: function(event,ui){
  $(this).addClass('hover');
}
```

On RECEIVE cancel the sort if the target doesn't have the have hover class. Cancel returns the lists to their state before the sort was started

```
receive: function(event,ui){
  if( !$(this).hasClass('hover')){
    $(this).sortable('cancel');
  }
}
```

This still leaves one more problem. The target won't respond to the OVER event again until some other target triggers an OVER event first.

List A
item 1
item 2

List B

item 3

1. Click on item 1, drag over List B: OVER event is triggered on List B
2. Continue dragging item 1 out of List B: OUT event is triggered on List B
3. Release item 1 in a location that is clear of both List A and List B: RECEIVE is triggered on List B (But we can cancel the sort if List B doesn't have the hover class still - which is removed by OUT in step 2.

This sequence shows how the assumed target can be cleared

1. Click on item 1, drag over List B: OVER event is triggered on List B
2. Continue dragging item 1 out of List B: OUT event is triggered on
   List B
3. Continue dragging item 1 over List B again: OVER event is NOT triggered
4. Continue dragging item 1 over List A: OVER event is triggered on List A
5. Continue dragging item 1 out of List A: OUT event is triggered on List A
6. Continue dragging item 1 over List B again: OVER event is triggered on List B

I am still looking for a way around this last problem as it requires the user to make extra motions with the drag to make the target active again (assume they want to drag item 1 from List A to List B but overshoot and now List B won't trigger MOVE the second time which means I can't put the hover class on it to show it is the active drop spot.

In conclusion, sortable triggers OUT, but still remembers the target in the event of drop which triggers RECEIVE, and also prevent